# TableView cell for row at index path is not beeing called every time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have created a class to generate tickets and when the ticket is generated I want to show it in the table view one by one.
I have created  a protocol for that class and once the ticket is prepared I send a message to its delegate which is `tableView` to reload the table view.
when the `reload` method is called on the  `tableView` `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` is being  called every time a new ticket is generated but the
`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is not being called every time the ticket is generated but once all the tickets are generated it is being called

below is the code

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (self.ticketGenerator == nil) {
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return self.ticketGenerator.ticketNumbers.count;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    HSEticketView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[HSEticketView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        [cell Tickets:[self.ticketGenerator.ticketNumbers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}

//to increase the height of the cell

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 135;
}

-(void)background
{
    [self.ticketGenerator GenerateNoOfTickets:[self.enteredNo.text intValue]:self];
}


- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {
    [self.enteredNo resignFirstResponder];
    self.enteredNo.hidden = YES;
    self.label.hidden = YES;
    self.button.hidden = YES;
    self.tableView.hidden = NO;

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(background) withObject:nil];
        NSLog(@"dgf");

}

#pragma ticketGenrate delgate methods

-(void)generationOfTicketCompleated
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];


}
```

Comment: Have you specified the delegates for the `UITableView` . If not then add _tableview.delegate=self; _tableview.dataSource=self; Also check your `numberOfRowsInSection:` Maybe the sections are returning 0 value .

Comment: May be your tableview nil when you reload data

Comment: No it is not nil the method is beeing called once all the tickets are generated

Comment: double check your delegates. Are you setting all of them properly..? Also, where are you updating your datasource of your tableview..?

Comment: May be u r redefining size of table in viewWillAppear or at some other....Once check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All changes to the UI must be done on the *main thread*. If you execute

```
[self.ticketGenerator GenerateNoOfTickets:...]
```

on a background thread and (as I assume) that functions calls

```
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:...]
```

that will not work, because `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` must be called on the main thread.

If you want to update the table view from a background thread, you can for example do

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    add item to data source array ...;
    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:...];
});
```

Comment: calling the [tableView reloadData] on the main thread solved the problem

Comment: @user1140129: You are welcome. - Just a note: Using `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` instead of `reloadData` might give a "smoother" UI update, because only the new rows are redrawn, instead of all rows.

Comment: Again Thank u for your suggestion I will try it and come back

Answer (score 0):

check your return self.ticketGenerator.ticketNumbers.count; is 0 then cellForRowAtIndexPath is not call or reload your tableview in ViewWillAppear like [reload YourTableViewName].

Answer (score 0):

Thank u Martin

the problem is I am doing the  [tableView reloadData] on another thread as uielements need to be run on main thread the method

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is not being called the solution i got is

```
-(void)generationOfTicketCompleated
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });

}
```

Comment: I don't know why you "unaccepted" my answer. I think that not updating the UI on the main thread was the crucial problem...

Comment: sorry i am new to stack over flow .I don't no that we can accept only one answer I haven't  seen that accepting another answer unaccepted your answer.